# MYSQL - get lowest bid from table group by product (results weird)

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, I am baffled to what is going on with my query but what I am trying to do is the following:
Get the lowest bid grouped by product_id and then load in the product information related to that bid.

Currently when running the below query it says to me that the bid_id where column product_id = 2 is 30 but its definetly not 30, it should be 120 (although the bid_price value is correct at 29.99):

```
SELECT lowbid.bid_id, lowbid.bid_price
FROM (SELECT bid_id, min(bid_price) AS bid_price, product_id FROM tbl_products_bid WHERE is_active = 1 AND is_deleted = 0 GROUP BY product_id) AS lowbid;
```

Now due to this query giving me random bid_id's, which I am not sure why I was wondering if a SQL guru could provide me with an insight to 1. if I am being totally thick or 2. if there is another way or why I could be getting that random bid_id not even related to that bid_price.

I have created a SQLFiddle which can explain what I mean but any help would be grateful.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de77b/14

Also just to let you know that this query is part of another query but I took out the element that I think is giving me an issue (i.e above)
The part of the bigger query is below:

```
SELECT lowestbid.bid_id, lowestbid.product_id, lowestbid.bid_price as seller_bid_price, seller_description, pb.is_countdown, pb.startdate, pb.enddate
FROM
  tbl_products_bid pb
  inner JOIN (
    SELECT bid_id, product_id, min(bid_price) as bid_price, seller_id, description as seller_description, is_countdown, startdate, enddate from tbl_products_bid where is_active = 1 group by product_id
  ) AS lowestbid ON pb.bid_id = lowestbid.bid_id
order by lowestbid.bid_price asc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tbl_products_bid a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  product_id, MIN(bid_price) min_price
            FROM    tbl_products_bid
            GROUP   BY product_id
        ) b ON  a.product_id = b.product_id AND
                a.bid_price = b.min_price
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de77b/23)