# Complex query join with doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, left-join

I'm building a query to show items with user and then show highest Bid on the item.

**Example**:

Xbox 360 by james. - the highest bid was $55.

art table by mario. - the highest bid was $25.

**Query**

```
SELECT i, u
FROM AppBundle:Item i
LEFT JOIN i.user u
```

I have another table bids (one to many relationship). I'm not sure how can I include single highest bid of the item in the same query with join.

I know I can just run another query after this query, with function (relationship), but I'm avoiding to do that for optimisation reasons.

**Solution**

SQL
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16538294/75799 - But how is this possible in doctrine DQL?

Comment: As an alternate idea, you could add an additional foreign key on item to the highest bid and update that whenever a bid is created that is the new highest bid. This would save you writing sub selects and would be relatively easy to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query may look something like

```
select i,u
from i
inner join bids u on i.id = u.item_id
WHERE
    i.value = (select max(value) from bids     where item_id = i.id)
group by i
```

DQL, I don't think supports subqueries, so you could try using a `Having` clause or see if `Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr` offers anything.

To solve this for my own case, I added a method to the origin entity (item) to find the max entity in a list of entities (bids), using Doctrine's Collections' `Criteria` I've written about it [here](https://shamil.co.uk/blog/rescued-by-doctrine-collections-criteria).

Your `Item` entity would contain

```
public function getMaxBid()
{
   $criteria = Criteria::create();
   $criteria->orderBy(['bid.value' => Criteria::ASC]);
   $criteria->setLimit(1);

   return $this->bids->matching($criteria);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for SQL example. but I need to see doctrine example. because there is always something different way of doing it, which is not normal sql way. which I'm not expert in yet.

Comment: @Basit I've updated the answer to provide more details and a code example.

Comment: @Basit included doctrine code. You might be able to move that up to the repository level, which I have not tried yet.

Comment: Thanks for the post, it is very useful and interesting method, which I didn't knew about. I will surely check repository and/or try this.

Comment: @Basit no worries - I ran into pretty much the same thing as you!

Comment: @Basit from my blog post: `That is, if the collection is:

already loaded, the filtering happens in-memory with PHP
not already loaded, the filtering is passed down to the database level`. I haven't checked to see what it does when you need the full lot afterwards. For each item, it will, sadly run as a separate query (as it is lazy loaded) The `O` is awful here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99739/discussion-between-bear-and-basit).

Comment: I have just run query with 20 list of items and limit the bids to 1 and display bidder name also. that came up to ^60 queries at runtime.

Comment: DQL supports subqueries. here is an example: https://github.com/zikula/core/blob/1.4/src/system/BlocksModule/Entity/Repository/BlockRepository.php#L24-L39

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IN` with a sub query in such cases.
I am not sure if I understood your model correctly, but I attempted to make your query with a `QueryBuilder` and I am sure you will manage to make it work with this example:

```
$qb  = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$sub = $qb;

$sub->select('mbi') // max bid item
    ->where('i.id = mbi.id')
    ->leftJoin('mbi.bids', 'b'))
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->max('b.value'))
    ->getQuery();

$qb = $qb->select('i', 'u')
         ->where($qb->expr()->in('i', $sub->getDQL()))
         ->leftJoin('i.user', 'u');

$query = $qb->getQuery();
return $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way that *i* know to find the maximum bid *and* the bidder with one grouping query, but there's several techniques to making the logic work with several queries.  You could do a sub select and that might work fine depending on the size of the table.  If you're planning on growing to the point where that's not going to work, you're probably already looking at sharing your relational databases, moving some data to a  less transactional, higher performance db technology, or denormalizing, but if you want to keep this implemented in pure MySQL, you could use a procedure to express in multiple commands how to check for a bid and optionally add to the list, also updating the current high bidder in a denormalized high bids table.  This keeps the complex logic of how to verify the bid in one, the most rigorously managed place - the database.  Just make sure you use transactions properly to stop 2 bids from being recorded  concurrently ( eg, SELECT FOR UPDATE).

I used to ask prospective programmers to write this query to see how experienced with MySQL they were, many thought just a max grouping was sufficient, and a few left the interview still convinced that it would work fine and *i* was wrong.  So good question!